# The uniqueness of solution to $1+2^{\log_3x}=x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have this equation: $$1+2^{\log_3x}=x \text{ where } x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Anyone can immediately see the solution, $x=3$, but the remaining problem is to prove that $x$ is the unique solution. We can process the equation a little so we have: $$ x-2^{\log_3x}=1 $$

So we have to prove that:

$$
\begin{align}
  & \text{let } f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R} \\
  & f(x) = x-2^{\log_3x} \text{ is injective}
\end{align}
$$

How can we do this by deriving the function?

Comment: $f$ is only defined for positive real $x$. - To simplify derivation, recall that $2^y=e^{y\ln 2}$ and $\log_3 x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}$

Comment: You don't have to prove that $f$ is injective. You only need to show that $f(x)=1$ has one solution. The equation $f(x)=17$ may well have multiple solutions for all we care. (I'm suggesting to consider whether you are setting yourself a task that is too difficult). How about simplifying $2^{\log_3 x}$, anyway?

Comment: @Minestrone, why would this be too difficult?

Comment: I don't know; I didn't think about the problem much. I objected to "We *have to* prove that" by saying no, we don't have to prove that.

Comment: @Minestrone, could you propose your solution in an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all
$$
2^{\log_3x}=e^{\tfrac{\log2}{\log3}x}=x^{\tfrac{\log2}{\log3}},\quad0<\frac{\log2}{\log3}<1.
$$
I will show that if $0<a<1$, then $1+x^a=x$ has a unique solution. If $0\le x\le1$, Then $x^a\ge x$, and there are no solutions on $[0,1]$. Next, it is easy to see that $f(x)=1+x^a-x$ is strictly decreasing on $(1,\infty)$. Since $f(1)=1>0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, there is a unique solution of $f(x)=0$ on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Are you using $\log 2$ as $\log_e2$? I am asking this because in my country, we use $\ln2$ for $\log_e2$.

Comment: Yes, for me $\log\equiv\ln$.